# Who knows Rand al’Thor’s parentage?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, genealogy

The Aiel know his father Janduin, and that his mother was a non-Aiel Maiden who called herself Shaiel. Rand himself figured out that Shaiel was Tigraine Mantear and was concerned whether that made him a cousin to Elayne. But has anyone else put this together?

Comment: Waiting for Galad’s reaction to his half-brother marrying his half-sister.

Comment: Can't like Rand any less than he does now...

Comment: Didn't one of the Andoran noblewomen clarify for Rand that Elayne being his "cousin" didn't mean what he thought it did?

Comment: @rsegal: I believe that was just a more general statement that Andoran nobles habitually overstate their relations to the first Queen and will thus effectively claim to be all "cousins" when it's really many times removed.

Comment: I don't believe he mentions it anywhere in [his profile](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven't explicitly seen that anyone else has figured this out.  Gitara Moroso knew in advance - she sent Tigraine to the Waste so that the Dragon could be reborn.  I wouldn't be surprised if Moiraine knew this, but isn't any actual evidence for that.